# How to change http request name in Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I need to change the http request name  dynamically. I am extracting a number from one request and i have to send that to next request name. Any ideas on how to do this ?
welcome !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract number to variable and use regular jmeter variable substitution:

```
Sampler number ${var_with_number}
```

Comment: Replacing request name with variable(UDV) has helped me to generate dynamic name. Thanks Thanks F2nd